# RNFirebase core module was not found natively on android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to run an existing react native app on android platform and I am getting the error as in the below image. I have already followed all the steps mentioned under http://invertase.link/android, but I still am facing this error.

I am a complete beginner in react native, have already exhausted all the solutions available on the web and this post is my last resort.

[image]

Comment: hey, i'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution? = same issue here

Comment: Same issue, stuck here

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;` and `new RNFirebasePackage()` in the MainApplication.java

Comment: You can also just run `react-native link react-native-firebase`.

Comment: @cheesussaysstopfiringmods for me `react-native link` adds `io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebaseAdMobPackage;` to `MainApplication.java` instead of  `RNFirebasePackage`.

Comment: On more recent versions of @react-native-fiirebase, this no longer works

Answer (score 1):

In my case I deleted my app from emulator and reinstall that by giving the command (react-native run-android) and that process worked for me.

Comment: This was down voted but this is also how I got it to work for me as well, after ensuring everything was configured correctly this is what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slim chance that this error is because your bundle generated by the `react-native bundle ...` command needs to be rebuilt.

I followed every other route unsuccessfully until I realised it was just this. *facepalm*.

Just in case this helps someone who's already spent a day or two.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same exact issue, and the underlying issue was that Invertase's starter project was already ejected from Expo and utilizing native modules. Expo was unable to link those. To integrate Firebase in Expo, I redid my project using `create-react-native-app`, copied all the source JS files over, [then followed this guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase/), doing `npm install --save firebase`. I had to reinstall all the dependencies again with npm, but integrating Firebase was much easier.